# Oracle Apex - Create a manual process for Editable Interactive Grid to check ROWNUM

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a editable IG that works flawlessly with default process but I need something more, for example:

I have a specific colunm named "MAIN ADDRESS" and with default process I need to manually set '0 - No' OR '1 - Yes' from a radio group.

Now I need a process to check if its the first row that I'm adding and automatically set YES (if its the first address that I'm adding) or NO (if not) to the colunm "Main Address" and then continues with the default process to insert on table.

And I'll have another 'process' to check if the row that I'm deleting is the "Main Address" and if YES set the first row of the IG as main address after deleting.

I'm trying to find something like ROWNUM on the IG when I'm adding a row (but before insert in the table).

Also, I'm using Oracle Application Express 5.1.4.00.08 in a Windows (7)

Any ideas?

Comment: From Patrick Wolf-Oracle on https://community.oracle.com/thread/3937159

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using Patrick Wolf instructions but I can't figure out how to check if its the first row that is getting inserted. Something like ROWNUM but 'just on the screen'

Comment: You have a rownum pseudocolumn, just create one more column in your select with rownum value. SELECT rownum, othercolumns FROM mytable. Now, in your PL/SQL you have the value of rownum like the other columns.

Comment: I'm assuming yes, I have not tested.

Comment: Instead of SELECT rownum use SELECT row_number() over ( order by cod desc) as rwnum. The order by should be the same of your principal query.